# How to get a platform native string for a QML Action shortcut?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a [Qt Quick Controls 2 Action](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-action.html) with a shortcut:

```
Action {
    id: myAction
    shortcut: "Ctrl+D"
}
```

How can I get a platform native representation of the shortcut?

Here is what I already tried:

- Using the shortcut right away like

  ```
  ToolTip.text: myAction.shortcut
  ```

  However, this returns the shortcut as defined (for example, `"Ctrl+D"`) and not a platform native representation (for example, `"⌘D"`). It also returns incorrect results in case a `StandardKey` is used because it gives the integer value of the `StandardKey` and not the corresponding key combination.
- Using a `nativeText` property like

  ```
  ToolTip.text: myAction.shortcut.nativeText
  ```

  But such a property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no straight forward way to get this.

A workaround is:

1. **Create a disabled `Shortcut` item**
   This will give us the platform native representation via its `nativeText` property.
2. **Derive from `Action` and add a custom property to hold the shortcut**
   This is necessary because the `shortcut` property of the `Action` will *always* return a string which will be interpreted incorrectly by the `Shortcut` item when using a `StandardKey` (the `Shortcut` item will interpret the integer value as the shortcut so you get a `"3"` instead of `"Ctrl+O"`).
3. **Bind the custom property to the `Action` shortcut and to the `Shortcut` sequence**

So in code:

CustomAction.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Action {
    /* Custom property */
    property var keySequence
    shortcut: keySequence
}
```

ToolTipButton.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Button {

    /* Disabled Shortcut */
    Shortcut {
        id: dummyShortcut
        enabled: false
        sequence: action.keySequence
    }

    hoverEnabled: true

    ToolTip.visible: hovered
    ToolTip.delay: 1000
    ToolTip.timeout: 5000
    ToolTip.text: dummyShortcut.nativeText
}
```

Used like this:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    CustomAction {
        id: myAction
        keySequence: StandardKey.Open
    }

    ToolTipButton {
        id: myButton
        action: myAction
        text: "Trigger my action"
    }

}
```